# Jquery .toggle only showing not hiding in Drupal view

Tags: javascript, drupal, view, jquery

I have a view of nodes in drupal. Each node has button which (is supposed to) toggle an extra row in a table. However, although I am able to toggle the extra row open, I am unable to toggle it shut again.

Here is the javascript;

```
Drupal.behaviors.morelink = function(context) {
  $("a.morelink").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.more').hide();
    $('.more').eq( $('a.morelink').index( $(this) ) ).toggle();
  });
}
```

Here is the button in my node-type.tpl.php;

```
<a class="morelink" href = "<?php print url('node/' . $node->nid); ?>">
<img src="greydown.png" ALT="More"></a>
```

Here is the extra row;

```
<tr class="more ">
<td> some content here</td>
</tr>
```

And here is the css;

```
.more {
  display:none;
}
```

Any ideas as to why I cannot toggle shut (hide it) again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably because you `hide` then `toggle` every time, which results in a `show`.  I.e.:

```
$('.more').hide();
$('.more').eq( $('a.morelink').index( $(this) ) ).toggle();
```

If you remove the `hide()`, you should be good.

Comment: Yessss! That was it. Thank you very much.